# Storing 100 vectors XNA

Tags: c#, xna, 2d-games

I'm making a 2D top down survival game, maximum sprite count for the top level is 100 sprites. 
When I use a random to generate their vector positions occasionally i'll get some overlap between sprites.

So to combat this i'm going to store some pre-defined positions.

**The question**

So my question is what would be the best way of storing these. Initially i was going to store them in an array, however i'm thinking that storing them in a text file and reading them in at the start of the game would be a better solution.

I'm a beginner so if anyone could give any advice on this it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes store them in a CSV (comma separated values) text file, or if you want, use a database, although I would recommend the former. Database storage sounds like overkill in your situation. On start-up you would load the values into an array. If you don't the game will lag every time it gets a value. You just need the text file for persistent storage and then the array for usage.

Hope this clears your issue up for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's the solution I implemented :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check if the position of the sprites overlap? If the sprites do not overlap often this should not add too much calculations and grands more randomness then a fixed position template.

What you do in the class for the entities with the sprite is add a public Rectangle, you probably already use a rectangle to draw them to the screen. Making this public allows you to do something like this in the class that generates the entities.

```
if (addSprite)
{
Entity newEntity = new Entity(random position);
foreach (Entity e in entityList)
{
if (newEntity.rectangle(Intersects(newEntity.rectangle))
{
//give a new position to newEntity and run this loop again
}
else
{
entityList.add(newEntity);
}
}
```

Comment: Would this be seen as a brute force approach? With a small viewport and so many sprites this could result in a lot of runs through the loop?